# Fazer validação reativa no angular com formgroup

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando colocar uma mensagem de erro no template, porém não estou conseguindo chegar no validator que criei.

Esse é o validator:

```
  criarFormularioDeUsuario() {
    this.formularioLogin = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
  }
```

No template eu tentei:

```
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="Email">
    <mat-error *ngIf="formularioLogin.email.errors.email">
        Você precisa entrar com um e-mail válido.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Também tentei com hasError:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="formularioLogin.hasError('email') || formularioLogin.hasError('required')">
```

Também não deu certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vc não precisa do compose.

```
this.formularioLogin = this.fb.group({
      email: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

Tenta:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="formularioLogin.get('email').errors">
        {{formularioLogin.get('email').errors|json}} //aqui vc vai ver os erros que estao dando
</mat-error>
```

Ou então

```
<div *ngIf="formularioLogin.get('email').errors.required">
    Email é requirido.
</div>
```